# Dynamic Required Fields in Form

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, webforms

I have a long form with too many fields. I wanted to make it a dynamic form, meaning that the required fields are different each time as desired. So i put a small  beside all form fields and have this code to dynamically choose which fields are required and check it, therefore when the user submit the form, the dynamic error text appears only beside the selected required fields. but the outcome is different that expected. The PHP error is being displayed beside all fields not only the desired in array. Please need your help.

```
$required = array('cm_name', 'cm_mobile', 'cm_mail', 'cm_dob', 'cm_income', 'cm_country');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach($required as $field) {
 if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $err_req = "* Required Data";
    $valid = true;
  } else {
    $err_req = "";
    $valid=false; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is changing the value of a variable inside your foreach loop. When you exit the loop, you either have a value assigned to your variable ($err_req = "* Required Data”) or you do not ($err_req = "”). This will result in either having all your fields having the "Required Data” text next to it, or none of them will have it. This is because the value of your variable gets overwritten with each iteration inside your loop.

What you want to do instead, is perform the operation of printing or not printing the error message next to each of your form input field inside your loop, or use a use a unique identifier for each place you want to display the error. This can be achieved in several ways, one would be by assigning an id to each of your empty error message next to your input field. For simplicity, the id could match your $required array values. If there is no value in your $field, you should change the value of your error text with the matching id.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function

```
function checkrequired($field,$req_fields)
{
    if(in_array($field,$req_fields)) {
        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && empty($_POST[$field])) {
            echo "* Missing Data";
        }
    }
}
```

And put beside each field this line

```
<?php checkrequired("cm_phone",$req_fields); ?>
```

And defined which fields are required like this

```
$req_fields = array('cm_name', 'cm_mobile', 'cm_mail', 'cm_dob', 'cm_income', 'cm_country', 'security_code');
```